# Stop music to play YouTube video?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

So I have a UIWebView that contains music that can be played in the app. In another view I have a list of YouTube videos that can be played in the app. However, when music is playing from the webView and then a YouTube video is started, the music doesn't stop, and overlaps the audio from the YouTube video.

How can I stop the music playing in a UIWebView when another UIWebView is playing a YouTube video? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

before play video, set this code.

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&sessionError];
```

more information, read a this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html